# How to fix this for loop is freezing my program

Tags: c#, loops

My goal is to *loop* through `List<weatherForecast> weatherList` and see whether or not it contains a specific value. However, every time I run the program, *it freezes*.

By commenting out sections of the loop, It seems that every thing besides the `foreach loop` is working, but I have used `foreach` statements nearly identical to this in other parts of the program, and they work fine.

```
Boolean flag;

for (DateTime day1 = DateTime.Parse(sDate); day1 <= DateTime.Parse(eDate); day1.AddDays(1))
{
    flag = false;

    foreach (WeatherForecast w in weatherList)
    {
        if (selected.Contains(w.City) && w.getDay().CompareTo(day1) == 0)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    if (!flag)
    {
        day1 = DateTime.Parse(eDate).AddDays(1);

        MessageBox.Show("Some of the dates in the range you selected do not have weather data. \nDefault data will be used,but you can enter the data manually.", "Missing Data", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should assign `day1` back `day1 = day1.AddDays(1)`

Comment: Also, you should probably move `DateTime.Parse` out of the loop - there is no need to repeat the same work over and over again.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for#the-iterator-section) section of your for loop:

```
for (DateTime day1 = DateTime.Parse(sDate); day1 <= DateTime.Parse(eDate); day1.AddDays(1))
```

It should read `day1 = day1.AddDays(1);`:

```
for (DateTime day1 = DateTime.Parse(sDate); day1 <= DateTime.Parse(eDate); day1 = day1.AddDays(1))
```

This is because `AddDays` doesn't modify the existing `DateTime` object; it returns a new instance of `DateTime`. You need to assign this back to your loop variable. In contrast, `++i` or `i++` work because they actually modify the value of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of the *infinite loop* is that you don't modify `day1` variable, you should assign `day1.Adddays(1)` back to `day1`:

```
for (DateTime day1 = DateTime.Parse(sDate); 
     day1 <= DateTime.Parse(eDate); 
     day1 = day1.AddDays(1))                // <- assign day1.AddDays(1) back to day1
{
  ....
}
```

When querying data (in your case looking for missed dates), try using *Linq* which has been specially designed for querying:

```
  DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(sDate).Date;
  DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(eDate).Date;

  var missingDates = Enumerable
    .Range(0, (endDate - startDate).Days + 1)
    .Select(day => startDate.AddDays(day))
    .Where(date => !weatherList.Any(w => selected.Contains(w.City) && w.getDate != date))
    .ToArray(); // Let's materialize them as an array

  if (missingDates.Any()) {
    //TODO: we have missingDates, let user know about it
    MessageBox.Show(
      $"You have {missingDates.Length} missing dates",
       "Missing Data", 
        MessageBoxButton.OK, 
        MessageBoxImage.Warning);
  }
```